# webview with iframe - back button goes back inside the iframe

Tags: android, iframe, android-webview

I have an android project, that shows only a web view. 
I use this function to go to the previous page with the back button of the device:

```
 @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);                  

                if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                    webView.goBack();
                    return true;
                } else {
                   // alert dialog...
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

and this function to go back to the previous page via js inside the web view:

```
goBack()
{
history.go(-1);
}
```

In these both functions, if the page contains an iframe, the page inside the iframe goes back, and not the parent page.

How can I make the parent page go back and not the page inside the iframe go back on clicking the back button?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
goBack() {

        if(webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            finish()
        }

}
```